# Why don't most medical practitioners conduct research?

Tags: research, general-practitioners

The vast majority of medical practitioners do not conduct any research. Is there any research/study/survey/… that tried to look at the reasons why most medical petitioners do not conduct any research?

Comment: I'm going to see if I can find any research into this. However, it is not usually a simple matter of choice as research posts are generally separate from clinical ones. Most doctors and nurses are not employed in academic or research roles, but rather in service-provision roles. Many consultants doing a doctorate (e.g. MD) will do research as part of this but most research is done by professionals employed in academic roles within a university or other institute (they may also have a clinical role at a hospital etc).